# SQL - Get Databasename from merged query filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon,

I have a working query, where I loop through all my databases, and filter down to check which report is being used where.  This works (see below)

I have this working query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      ReportPath VARCHAR(500)
      )

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = STUFF((SELECT '

UNION ALL
' + 'SELECT path FROM ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.ReportConfig where path like ''%/Standard Reports/Booking/Booked Out by Location%'' and Active = 1'
from sys.Databases 
WHERE name LIKE 'SFB-%' 
FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,15,'')

INSERT #temp
execute(@SQL)

SELECT  ReportPath FROM #temp
```

And this is giving me the following output:

[image]

So I know that out of my 90 databases, the report is being used 6 times, but I don't know where.

So I want to include the database name of where this report is being used.
I googled around and tried a bunch of things, but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean that you want to get all of the databases referenced by the source queries used in those reports?

Comment: You're using the name in `quotename(name)`. You can probably change your dynamic query to `SELECT name, path.......` to get what you're after.

Comment: Also, by putting the `%`s around both sides of your `LIKE` filter, you're excluding any index you may have on that column. If all your reports start with that text, remove the first wildcard `%`. It should speed up the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small tweak to what you already have will get you there

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

--Add a column to your temp table
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      DatabaseName varchar(100)
      ,ReportPath VARCHAR(500)
      )

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

--adjust your dynamic query and add the [name] column as shown below
set @SQL = STUFF((SELECT '

UNION ALL
' + 'SELECT ''' + [name] + ''' as DatabaseName,path FROM ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.ReportConfig where path like ''%/Standard Reports/Booking/Booked Out by Location%'' and Active = 1'
from sys.Databases 
WHERE name LIKE 'SFB-%' 
FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,15,'')

INSERT #temp
execute(@SQL)

SELECT  DatabaseName, ReportPath FROM #temp
```

Comment: You're going to want to wrap `[name]` in single quotes, and maybe toss an `AS DatabaseName` alias on there. But, yeah, like this.

Comment: @EricBrandt if they wrapped [name] with quotes that would basically put that verbiage in the query and not the actual database name.  right?  The select from sys.Database isn't in the context of what gets executed.  They're using sys.database to build the query.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't very clear there. In the dynamic SQL part, it should be `'SELECT ''' + [name] + ''' AS DatabaseName ,path FROM '`, so that the name of the database is treated as a string  rather than an object identifier by the materialized query.

Comment: Assuming I'm picturing the output correctly. And I'm not batting a thousand this morning, so take me with a grain of salt.